# How do I get a full path to a program in linux?

Tags: linux, mono

I need to get to the full path of mono because it seems things are messing up when I just use the command "mono" through cronjobs

I have this: /usr/etc/mono

But I also have this: /usr/local/src/mono-2.10.2/mono

I'm not sure what i'm suppose to link it to. Any ideas please?

Comment: Should probably be `/usr/bin/mono`. `etc` is not for binaries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at the output of

```
$ which mono
```

Comment: @JosipGòdlyZirdum Glad to help. Consider accepting the answer if you were satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `/usr/etc/mono`, as the other path looks like a source tree.